# Importing InDesign layers into After Effects

Tags: adobe-indesign, adobe-after-effects

I'm building a webpage layout in Indesign, and my client wants me to make an animated demo of it. I can do this in After Effects, but I don't want to recreate the entire site in AE.

Is there a way I can import all my layers from Indesign directly into After Effects?

Comment: Is the video just for the clients amusement or is it actually gonna be used for something? Cause if it's just for the client, I might consider coding the basic "frame" of the site with the animations. Also, this question comes to mind: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36906/how-to-create-an-animated-demo-of-my-webdesign

Comment: To kind of explain why I tried my best to offer alternatives to what you are asking: AE can't import .indd files and .png export from indesign isn't exactly super fast or easy. Maybe there's a script, but I wouldn't hold my breath. The best option that came to my mind was exporting it to pdf and then with AI making sure that each object is on their own layer ( with a script maybe ). Layered .pdf and .ai files can be imported to AE as separate assets. ...OR just export layers to png files in AI ( with another script ). That's what I would prefer, as it's easier to manage with AE.

Comment: not the answer you are looking for but AE would not be my goto for this. I'd look at using some kind of prototyping tool. Either a quick and dirty animation in Keynote.app (OS X only) or a full prototyping setup with interactive animation in Quartz Composer and Facebook's prototyping plugin called Origami. There are responsive website demo files on the Facebook Origami Community page if you search files for "responsive". Big learning curve but worth it if you want to animate prototypes.

Comment: you could output as PDF and then import to AE and even convert to shapes if using small files.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend exporting as a PDF to Illustrator, and then in Illustrator ungrouping or otherwise breaking up the graphics into whatever pieces you might need to animate in After Effects.